# How to eradicate Windows and UEFI from a computer

Tags: linux, windows-10, bios, uefi

I have bought an HP laptop, *HP Pavilion 15 cw1010ur*, and I super shouldn't have.

**I tried** to install a Linux distribution on it, but the Linux kernel in the live USB is having problems allocating memory. Also, the specific UEFI of this laptop lacks 99% of features that I need and is in desperate need of replacement.

I would like help from people familiar with the inner workings of UEFI and its alternatives, and how they interact with the rest of the machine. I am asking for help with the following matters:

**1) Completely remove Windows from the laptop.** I want this because Windows 10 might have, for a lack of a better word, defiled parts of the laptop that you wouldn't expect an OS to have access to. The goal is to clean the laptop to a point where it would seem that after the laptop was assembled, only UEFI was flashed on the motherboard and *nothing else* was done to it.

1.1) If possible, preserve the enrolled Windows 10 key currently stored in UEFI. I know how to extract the key, but I would like to know if it would be usable after bulletpoint one.

**2) Replace UEFI with Tianocore or another open source alternative.** I want this because UEFI is proprietary and the specific UEFI or my laptop is quite simply lacking an absurd amount of features, with at least one confirmed case of a broken setting (changing the value does nothing). The goal is, together with bulletpoint one, to eradicate all proprietary code from my laptop for the purpose of peace of mind.

The goal is to have a laptop with nothing getting in the way between me and Linux, after all stated above.

I apologize if some of the wording I used seemed over the top. I have a bias due to my pure hatred against the current trend of corporations screwing over users and users gobbling it up.

Comment: By the way, I have a suspicion that the best course of action in my case is to just refind the laptop and buy a more Linux-friendly one. I would like a person erudite in the matter to comment on my suspicion.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to replace the UEFI firmware on an OEM PC due to all OEMs locking the firmware to a single signing cert, and unless a new firmware image is signed by that specific cert, it's impossible to flash _(the firmware will not allow the flashing process to even begin it's next phase with the lack of that digital signature)_.  As to Windows, simply format the HDD; many Linux distros require the enabling of CSM [Legacy] boot and disabling Secure Boot in the UEFI firmware settings.

Comment: You should get a laptop [supported by coreboot](https://doc.coreboot.org/mainboard/index.html) if you want to get rid of UEFI. I'd suggest a Thinkpad. (Their UEFI may even be rich enough to be sufficient even before flashing, if you don't mind non-free firmware). Don't hope for anything modern, developing UEFI is not a trivial task and takes time. You'll probably have to flash directly to memory chip on the motherboard, it voids warranty and can damage hardware if done improperly. Dell's Latitude and XPS lines also run Linux pretty well in my experience and UEFI is very configurable.

Comment: By the way, HP is known for using exotic hardware that's not always well-supported on Linux. HP and Lenovo tend to whitelist hardware in UEFI, so eg. laptop will refuse to boot with WiFi/4G module that wasn't blessed by manufacturer. Dell doesn't. If you're a demanding user, I'd really recommend a business-oriented laptop, like Dell Latitude/Precision or Lenovo ThinkPad. Their UEFI setups are richer in features, they have better support (incl. firmware updates that improve Linux compatibility) and hardware maintainability is way better.

Comment: Honestly this is just a rant and your first comment is the best way of action. Return the notebook it doesn't fit your use case. Unless you go into more depth as to what has been "defiled" you won't find a better answer than just formatting the HDD and disabling secure boot.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I have disabled secure boot the moment I took the laptop out of the box. I have been interested in Dell for quite a while, and seeing that people recommend it, I think I have made up my mind. Thank you once more.